# Why does using continue with for-let cause an infinite loop?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

When I use `let` to declare my counter in a `for` loop, I see strange behavior if I use `continue`, like an infinite loop, as though my final expression isn't being evaluated. Here's a small test case:

```
node --harmony --use-strict --eval "for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) { continue; }"
```

This spins forever, but it works if I use `var` or move my declaration outside of the `for` initialization.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug present on node v0.12.2. See [V8 issue 3683, C-style for-let can't handle continue](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/v8/issues/detail?id=3683). It's fixed if you upgrade to v5.7.0.